# Making labels bold on hover makes the container shift

Tags: html, css, radio-group

When I hover the labels for my radio buttons, I would like them bold. However, this causes the container to change its width. Is there a way to have to keep the same container width when the labels are bold that would work in all major recent versions of browsers?

[jfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7gL038jd/2/)

Here is my html code:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <b class="group-label">from</b>
    <span class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="from-hiragana" name="from" value="true">
      <label for="from-hiragana">
        <span>Hiragana</span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="from-katakana" name="from" value="true">
      <label for="from-katakana">
        <span>Katakana</span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="from-romaji" name="from" value="true">
      <label for="from-romaji">
        <span>Romaji</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is my css code:

```
.input-wrapper {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-wrapper label:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s font-weight;
}

.input-wrapper span::before,
.input-wrapper span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.input-wrapper span::hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.input-wrapper span::before {
  left: -20px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span::after {
  left: -17px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #98fbc9;
  transition: left .25s, background-color .25s;
}

.group-label {
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: You accepted my answer and now you removed it any issue regarding of the same

Comment: Yes, it appears that the spacing between every input wrapper will always vary with this solution. https://jsfiddle.net/7gL038jd/9/

Comment: Okay you can reduse `max-width` if you don't need space

Comment: Yes, but I need consistent spacing between input-wrappers ^^

Comment: I updated answer you can get it by using `text-shadow` i posted working fiddle also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use text-shadow to make the text look bold. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/junaidkbr/7gL038jd/6/)

```
.input-wrapper label:hover {
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  text-shadow:1px 0px 0px black;
  transition: 0.3s text-shadow;
}
```

Comment: Cross browser is a very broad statement, so it's worth noting this will fail on IE 9 and older. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-textshadow

Comment: I updated my question. What's important is that it works in all major recent browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the labels position to fixed and extend your margin right on the wrapper.

```
.input-wrapper {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you get it by using `text-shadow` like following

**[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/7gL038jd/11/)**

You can get by `max-width` and `flex` like following

CSS Changes

```
.input-wrapper label:hover {
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  text-shadow:1px 0px 0px #000;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-wrapper label:hover {
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  text-shadow:1px 0px 0px #000;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.input-wrapper span::before,
.input-wrapper span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.input-wrapper span::hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.input-wrapper span::before {
  left: -20px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span::after {
  left: -17px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #98fbc9;
  transition: left .25s, background-color .25s;
}

.group-label {
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <b class="group-label">from</b>
    <span class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="from-hiragana" name="from" value="true">
      <label for="from-hiragana">
        <span>Hiragana</span>
    </label>
    </span>
    <span class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="from-katakana" name="from" value="true">
      <label for="from-katakana">
        <span>Katakana</span>
    </label>
    </span>
    <span class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="from-romaji" name="from" value="true">
      <label for="from-romaji">
        <span>Romaji</span>
    </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```